# Refresh Events in PrimeNG schedule in angular 6

Tags: fullcalendar, angular6, primeng

I want to refresh event on dropdown change by calling an api but it is giving me below error and not refreshing the events in the schedule control. I am using angular 6 version, PrimeNG 6.1.5 and fullcalendar 4.0.0-alpha version.

> CalendarDisplayComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: this.calendar.removeEventSources is not a function
>       at Schedule.push../node_modules/primeng/components/schedule/schedule.js.Schedule.ngDoCheck (schedule.js:248)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9253)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10514)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10476)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11109)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11069)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (CalendarDisplayComponent.html:2)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11061)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10458)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:10699)

Ts file :`

```
this.baseService.getcalendarSearchResult(event).subscribe(resp => {
        if (resp) {
            this.events = [];
            this.events = [
                { "Id": 384596, "title": "HR-Infotag", "start": "2018-10-16T08:00:00", "end": "2018-10-16T18:00:00", "editable": false, "Overlap": false, "ClassName": "" },
                { "Id": 384597, "title": "HR-Infotag", "start": "2018-10-17T08:00:00", "end": "2018-10-17T18:00:00", "editable": false, "Overlap": false, "ClassName": "" }
            ];
            // this._sharedService.setCalendarAPIResponse(this.events)
            //this.router.
        }
    })
```

HTML file code :

```
p-schedule [events]="events" [header]="header" [defaultDate]="defaultDate" [editable]="true" [options]="options"></p-schedule>
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you look at the docs you'll see the way of removing event sources has changed in v4. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/EventSource-remove - you have to get an event source object and then call the method on that, rather than the calendar. Did you not check the documentation??

Comment: Please find the above code edited in question  to bind the events again

Comment: I am using prime ng schedule control here

Comment: the code you've posted doesn't appear to be relevant to the error at all. The error is saying there's no such method called "removeEventSources" on the "calendar" object. The code you've posted doesn't contain a call to that method, so it can't be the part which is calling the error. Your browser will point you to the line of code which generated the error, so it's easy to find it. Then you need to replace it with the syntax in the link I gave you above. P.S. The fact you're using primeng is largely irrelevant here, it's just a wrapper round fullCalendar, which is where the change in method is

Comment: The only way primeNG could be a factor here is if it's their code which is trying to call a non existent function. Possibly they don't support this alpha version of fullCalendar yet, since it's not a full, tested release. Did you check that?

Comment: I have change the angular version of my solution from 6 to 5.2 and according the prime ng and full calendar versions also and now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have did some Rnd on the above question and finally I have change the angular version from 6 to 5.2 and according I have change the prime ng and full calendar(3.9) versions and now everything is working fine.
I have read in one of th article that there is compatibility issue between angular 6 and prime ng schedule